# Why is my upperRange2 column returning NULL occasionally. Am I abusing CTE's?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set that I am going to perform two separate random lottery pulls from. I wanted to do this lottery without a loop statement and thought CTEs were working great. As they always work for the first random selection. But when I try to chain a second repeat of the same logic I start to get random behavior out of the database. Specifically my upperRange2 field is sometimes NULL. Run the code below several times and you should see that sometimes upperRange2 has the proper value, and sometimes it just has NULL. If you only select from the candidatesSelected CTE you will see that the upperRange field always works. This issue only happens when I try to follow this pattern twice for two different random selections.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[RandomNumberView]
AS
    SELECT RAND() AS randomNumber
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRandoms] (
    @lowerRange int,
    @upperRange int,
    @count int
)
RETURNS @randoms TABLE (
    [randomNumber] int primary key
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@lowerRange IS NOT NULL 
        AND @upperRange IS NOT NULL 
        AND @count IS NOT NULL 
    )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @candidateCount int,
                @random float,
                @selected int

        /* This is the numbers that are possible to be selected
        ** from the user specified range. */
        SELECT @candidateCount = (@upperRange - @lowerRange) + 1

        /* If the user specified a count that is greater than the
        ** candidate count, then return every possibility between
        ** the lower and upper range even though its less than
        ** the count requested. */
        IF (@count > @candidateCount)
            INSERT @randoms 
                SELECT i 
                FROM Seq(@lowerRange, @upperRange)

        /* So that we don't select duplicate numbers keep grabbing
        ** a unique random number until the user specified count
        ** has been reached from the range specified. */
        WHILE (@count <= @candidateCount AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @randoms) < @count)
        BEGIN
            /* Note the use of the RandomNumberView.  It is forbidden
            ** to use non-deterministic functions in functions, which
            ** is why there isn't a call to RAND() here instead.  The
            ** RandomNumberView is just a boxing mechanism around the
            ** RAND() function so that it turns it into a table type
            ** source instead of a function and is therefore allowed. */
            SELECT @random = randomNumber FROM RandomNumberView

            /* To understand how the percentile random number is reduced
            ** to the range specified by the user consider this statement
            ** that produces a range of 0 to 6: ROUND(RAND() * 6, 0) */
            SELECT @selected = ROUND(@random * (@candidateCount - 1), 0) + @lowerRange
            IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @randoms WHERE randomNumber = @selected))
                INSERT @randoms VALUES (@selected)
        END
    END

    RETURN
END
GO

declare @candidates table (name varchar(10) primary key, [weight] int not null, secondaryWeight int not null);
insert @candidates values ('Carl', 2, 1);
insert @candidates values ('James', 1, 2);
insert @candidates values ('Randy', 3, 1);
insert @candidates values ('David', 2, 2);
insert @candidates values ('Michael', 1, 1);

declare @pickCount int = 2;

with
    candidateRows as (
        select
            name,
            [weight],
            secondaryWeight,
            row_number() over (order by [weight]) as [row]
        from @candidates
    ),
    candidateLowerRanges as (
        select
            name,
            [weight],
            secondaryWeight,
            [row],
            (
                select sum([weight])
                from candidateRows b
                where b.[row] <= a.[row]
            ) as upperRange
        from candidateRows a
    ),
    candidateFullRanges as (
        select
            name,
            [weight],
            secondaryWeight,
            [row],
            upperRange,
            lag(upperRange, 1, 0) over (order by upperRange) as previousUpperRange
        from candidateLowerRanges
    ),
    candidatesSelected as (
        select
            name,
            [weight],
            secondaryWeight,
            [row],
            upperRange,
            previousUpperRange,
            randomNumber
        from candidateFullRanges s
            inner join GetRandoms(1, (select max(upperRange) from candidateLowerRanges), @pickCount) r
                on s.upperRange >= r.randomNumber
                    and s.previousUpperRange < r.randomNumber               
    ),
    secondRows as (
        select
            name,
            [weight],
            secondaryWeight,
            [row],
            upperRange,
            previousUpperRange,
            randomNumber,
            row_number() over (order by secondaryWeight desc) as [row2]
        from candidatesSelected
    ),
    secondUpperRanges as (
        select
            name,
            [weight],
            secondaryWeight,
            [row],
            upperRange,
            previousUpperRange,
            randomNumber,
            row2,
            (
                select sum(secondaryWeight)
                from secondRows b
                where b.[row] <= a.[row]
            ) as upperRange2
        from secondRows a
    )
select *
from secondUpperRanges
```

Comment: "It is forbidden to use non-deterministic functions in functions"? Do you know why that is the case? SQL Server is doing that to enforce determinism on the function, and **MAY NOT CALL THE USER DEFINED FUNCTION A SECOND TIME WITH THE SAME PARAMETERS** thus effectively re-using the prior value out of `rand()`.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance, I didn't realize it always treated all functions as deterministic.  Since I didn't see any way to mark it up either way I thought the engine was analyzing it to determine if it has any non-deterministic functions used within it.  Thanks for pointing me probably back to the real problem, as I've been mislead into thinking it had something to do with using it twice in a sequence.

Comment: Also I would mark your answer as correct but its a comment.  I just went in and removed the use of the GetRandoms function and the behavior ended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is "side-effecting" not determinism or the lack thereof. (My comment this morning was not exactly correct in the details.)

["User-defined functions cannot be used to perform actions that modify the database state."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320(v=sql.120).aspx)

Why? I am not sure. I think the fact that calling a function during a read having the potential to change the results that would be returned is at the heart of it. You could end up with different results depending on what order SQL Server read rows. One should not need to know the order of work within a query. Stuff like that.

*`RAND(.5)` is deterministic but still can't be used in a function.*

["RAND is deterministic only when a seed parameter is specified."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f() RETURNS FLOAT AS BEGIN
    RETURN RAND(.5)
END
```

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 1, Procedure f, Line 3 
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'rand' within a function.

*So what's side-effecting about `RAND()`?*

Pseudo random number generators typically have an internal state. When a number is gotten from the generator two things happen. The internal state is updated and a "random" number is returned. The number and new state is strictly determined by a seed, if provided, or the state as it was when the function started. That internal state is global at some level within SQL Server. So `RAND()` always changes state, but is deterministic when provided a seed.

*Nondetermistic functions can be used in a user defined function.*

`GETDATE()` is nodetermistic, but not "side-effecting".

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.f() RETURNS datetime AS BEGIN
    RETURN GETDATE()
END
GO
PRINT dbo.f()
```

> Nov 20 2015  1:27PM

*Boxing the call to `RAND()` inside the view hid `RAND()`'s side effecting nature, did it hide `RAND()`'s non determinism?*

No. I can not find a system view to query to determine if SQL Server thinks a function is deterministic or not, but we can try to use the function as if it were, and observe the error.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[RandomNumberView]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT RAND() AS randomNumber
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyRand() RETURNS FLOAT 
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result FLOAT
    SELECT @Result = randomNumber
    FROM dbo.RandomNumberView
    RETURN @Result
END
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.T (Col int
    , ColC AS dbo.MyRand() PERSISTED)
```

> Msg 4936, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Computed column 'ColC' in table 'T' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

*So `dbo.MyRand()` is non-deterministic, why isn't it working again?*

["One caveat of almost all nondeterministic functions is that they are executed once per statement, not once per row. ... The only exception to this rule is NEWID, which will generate a new GUID for every row in the statement."](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-functions-the-basics/)

Determinism and nondeterminism are used determine whether a value can be safely persisted. You can't persist `GETDATE()` if it is used in a computed column or view, because the value will be different tomorrow than it is today. The value for `dbo.MyRand()` and `rand()` will be different on the next `SELECT` so it must be recomputed and not pulled from a persistent source.

However the writers of SQL Server have decided that within a single statement, they will only guarantee at least one call if one or more values are needed. It is nice that a single statement looks like it happened at the same time when using `GETDATE()`. This "feature" is a pain when trying to use randomness in a single statement.

---

**Note:** It sounds like randomness of the PRNG is important to your application. Evaluating randomness is beyond my ken. There are other methods of getting randomness at the row level within a query on SQL Server, some of which involve using `NEWID` which is evaluated per row. However, if randomness were important, *I* would not use them. See [Random Sampling in T-SQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175776(v=sql.80).aspx).